# How to combine while and if for iteration?

Tags: arcpy, iterator, loop

[image]

I want to calculated sum of the 'Inverse_DIST' of same 'IN_FID'

I use the arcpy.da.updatecursor of python code as follows

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\Auto_Logit\Neartable.gdb"
nc = max(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("D:\Auto_Logit\Neartable.gdb\SP_15km_sewage", ['IN_FID']))

i = 0
j = 1
sum = 0

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("SP_15km_sewage",("OBJECTID","IN_FID","Inverse_DIST","Sum_Inverse_DIST")) as cursor :
    for row in cursor :
        while row[0] == j and row[1] == i :
            j = j + 1
            sum += row[2]
            if row[1] == i :
                row[3] = sum
            elif row[1] != i :
                i = i + 1
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

As a result, as follows my python code not working iteration

How to doing iteration working from my code??

Comment: In what way is your code not working?  Try using some `print` statements to see what is being run and what is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use another approach, without while loop but iterating over the unique values for which you want to calculate a sum:

```
import arcpy

fc = r"D:\Auto_Logit\Neartable.gdb\SP_15km_sewage"

## first get a list of unique IN_FID values
fid_list = sorted({row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "IN_FID")})

## then iterate over these IN_FID values: for each IN_FID, 
## calculate the sum of the Inverse_DIST field values and add it to the sum field.
for fid in fid_list:
    exp = """IN_FID = '{}'""".format(fid)
    sum = 0
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "Inverse_DIST", exp) as cur_sum:
        for row_sum in cur_sum:
            sum += row_sum[0]

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "Sum_Inverse_DIST", exp) as cur:
        for row in cur:
            row[0] = sum
            cur.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice and help, it is very contribution in my research study. Expressing gratitude once again.

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import arcpy
input = r"C:\....\test\New File Geodatabase.gdb\line"
output = r"C:\....\test\New File Geodatabase.gdb\line_statistic"
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(input, output, "Shape_Leng SUM", "Code")
```

Shape_Leng - is your Invers_Dist
SUM - is the code for summarize 
Code - is you IN_FID

is sure to work couse under Analysis Tools\Statistics\Summery, is a tool to make this problem without coding.

Comment: Florjan - when adding a code block use the `{}` button to format as code (or just indent each line by 4 spaces)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. You who have provided your are very simple. it is a good imformation for my future research